# How to load postman(rest client) with imported collection using webdriver

Tags: selenium

I want to test certain API's using postman extension for chrome. Now all the apis have to be imported before i begin the testing.
Is there a way through which i can make Selenium Webdriver remember the loaded collections?

Comment: My answer not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting. Is the plan to use WebDriver to directly manipulate Postman?

From the Postman [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/collections)

"You can import a collection file. Click on the 'Import' button on the top bar, and paste a URL to the collection, or the collection JSON itself, and click 'Import'."

Perhaps Jayway's [rest-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) would be easier to work with? That is how I do it.